# Full-width table, truncate cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a table in HTML like this:

[image]

The table is:

```
<table class="table" style="font-size:22px; width:100%">
```

I would like to have everything fit into the page's width. And if it can't fit, then I would like the team names to be truncated with an ellipsis. Is this possible with HTML?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
<style>
  table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }    
</style>
```

And here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wn6c6yeL/

Comment: Why did you tagged your question with twitter bootstrap? What do you use it?

Comment: I am using bootstrap in the linked page, not sure if this is related to my problem since TWBS also has its own styling for tables

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle? I have a feeling that the issue lies in the parent div of your table being set beyond the width of the page so your table is technically doing what you tell it to.

Comment: Also, if you are using bootstrap look at their responsive tables, they have a pretty nice one that will re-size the info for you.

Comment: Is it practical if you set fixed widths on all columns except the ellipsis one?

Comment: Yes, fixed widths for the others is OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. All you need to do is to add `max-width` property to your `td`. Like this:

```
table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width:100px;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wn6c6yeL/1/)